# AtomicReader and KNearestNeighbour train() method

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I am trying to classify text docs using lucene 4.4. I am using the KNearestNeighbour class(call it KNN for ease) for this. I have indexed all the documents but I am stuck up with using the train method of KNN class, which takes an AtomicReader as an argument (along with three more arguments.). I passed IndexReader (with/without type casting to AtomicReader) as the argument but its gives an error. AtomicReader is the subclass of IndexReader. Maybe this is the problem.

But my query is how to create an AtomicReader object and pass it to the train method.It appears to me that the way to create AtomicReader on an index is different from creating IndexReader.(Atomic reader is an abstract class so we might have to use an object of its subclass).

Following is my code snippet. {indexLoc} is the directory path where I have created my index. {knn} is an object of KNearestNeighbour class which is a data member of my class.

```
public void startClassification() {

    try {
            StandardAnalyzer analyzer1 = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_44);
            FSDirectory index = FSDirectory.open(new File(indexLoc));

            /*(???how to create an appropriate AtomicReader object)*/
            IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(index);

            knn = new KNearestNeighborClassifier(k);
            knn.train(reader, "content", "category", analyzer1);
            classifyTestData();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain an `AtomicReader` by iterating over the `leaves` of your `IndexReader`:

```
for (AtomicReaderContext context : reader.leaves()) {
    final AtomicReader atomicReader = context.reader();
    knn.train(atomicReader, "content", "category", analyzer1);
}
```

While a `DirectoryReader` is an `IndexReader`, that has one or more sub-readers - for each segment of your index - an `AtomicReader` is an `IndexReader`, that does not have any sub-readers. Thus, an `AtomicReader` sees documents from only one segment and contains "global" docIds from `context.docBase` to `context.docBase + reader.maxDoc()`

Comment: Thanks. Is there any proper usage documentation for KNearestNeighbour class ? I have implemented my program following is the summary of it. 
Two initial classes - 
1. clothing (~180 train instances ,  10 test examples)
2. automotive (~180 train instances , 10 test examples).
code snippet - 

ClassificationResult thisclass = knn.assignClass(siteText); 
System.out.println(thisclass.getAssignedClass() );
System.out.println(thisclass.getScore());

Output is- 
[61 75 74 6f 6d 6f 74 69 76 65]
1.0
How do i interpret this result to {clothing/automotive} ?

Comment: Thanks. My above doubt is cleared now. knn.assignClass(siteText) returns a BytesRef object and to view the the result we have to convert the encoding.